# Intriguing behavior when set prototype on Constructor in javaScript

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype-programming

Begin with an simple attempt, I defined an Constructor and used it to create an instance `myobject`:

```
function MyConstructor () {};
var myobject = new MyConstructor ();
```

Then, I modified the `prototype` property of this Constructor and created another instance `myobject1` with it:

```
MyConstructor.prototype = {};
var myobject1 = new MyConstructor ();
```

I repeated the same procedure and created another instance `myobject2`:

```
MyConstructor.prototype = {name: '2'};
var myobject2 = new MyConstructor ();
```

Now I am testing the `constructor` property of each instance, which is not what I expect:

```
myobject.constructor == MyConstructor;
//true
myobject1.constructor == MyConstructor;
//false
myobject2.constructor == MyConstructor;
//false
```

When looking up the [[prototype]], it is different from each other.

```
myobject.__proto__ == myobject1.__proto__
//false
myobject2.__proto__ == myobject1.__proto__
//false
```

Could anyone explain what happens to `MyConstructor` when changing its `prototype` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you creating constructor:

```js
function MyConstructor() {};
```

it has prototype.constructor set to MyConstructor:

```js
MyConstructor.prototype.constructor === MyConstructor; //true
```

When you overwrite prototype of MyConstructor by

```js
MyConstructor.prototype = { foo: function () {} };
```

then origignal MyConstructor.prototype object is replaced by passed object { foo: function () {} } and this object does not have property 'constructor' set to MyConstructor but to function Object because Object is constructor bound to all object created by object literals.

So after this:

```
MyConstructor.prototype = { foo: function () {} };
MyConstructor.prototype.constructor === Object;
```

and when you create new object with this constructor

```js
var foo = new MyConstructor();
```

then:

```js
foo.constructor === Object; // true
```

so to repair this problem, after you overwrite prototype then you have to correct constructor field:

```js
MyConstructor.prototype = { foo: function () {} };
MyConstructor.prototype.constructor = MyConstructor;
```

and then your constructor has prototype with correct constructor field.
You could also write:

```js
MyConstructor.prototype = { foo: function () {}, constructor: MyConstructor };
```

and final effect will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is held in prototype.  By destroying the prototype with {} you effectively remove any reference to the constructor.